How to add UART support for DTS and compile it for STM32MP157F-DK2
I created a custom linux image for this target using the distribution package + x-linux-qt and the image "st-image-qt". This image is working correctly on my target.
Now, I want to add UART5 and UART4 to receive data over those 2 serial ports. As far as I understand, I need to add something like this in the DTS
&usart4 {
        pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep", "idle";/* pin configurations definition */
        pinctrl-0 = <&usart4_pins_a>; /* default pin configuration selection */
        pinctrl-1 = <&usart4_sleep_pins_a>; /* sleep pin configuration selection */
        pinctrl-2 = <&usart4_idle_pins_a>; /* idle pin configuration selection */
        status = "okay";

};

and something like this in the DTSI
   usart3_pins_a: usart3-0 {
            pins1 {
                    pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('B', 10, AF7)>, /* USART3_TX */
                             <STM32_PINMUX('G', 8, AF8)>; /* USART3_RTS */
                    bias-disable;
                    drive-push-pull;
                    slew-rate = <0>;
            };
            pins2 {
                    pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('B', 12, AF8)>, /* USART3_RX */
                             <STM32_PINMUX('I', 10, AF8)>; /* USART3_CTS_NSS */
                    bias-disable;
            };
    };

    usart3_idle_pins_a: usart3-idle-0 {
            pins1 {
                    pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('B', 10, ANALOG)>, /* USART3_TX */
                             <STM32_PINMUX('G', 8, ANALOG)>, /* USART3_RTS */
                             <STM32_PINMUX('I', 10, ANALOG)>; /* USART3_CTS_NSS */
            };
            pins2 {
                    pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('B', 12, AF8)>; /* USART3_RX */
                    bias-disable;
            };
    };

    usart3_sleep_pins_a: usart3-sleep-0 {
            pins {
                    pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('B', 10, ANALOG)>, /* USART3_TX */
                             <STM32_PINMUX('G', 8, ANALOG)>, /* USART3_RTS */
                             <STM32_PINMUX('I', 10, ANALOG)>, /* USART3_CTS_NSS */
                             <STM32_PINMUX('B', 12, ANALOG)>; /* USART3_RX */
            };
    };

My question is, should I override these files in my tmp-glibc/work-shared folder? or do I need to create new ones in my custom layer?
There's so much different paths and different documentation that I don't really understand which one should I be using

You have only mentioned some filename extensions rather than actual files. Typically the SoC manufacturer supplies a baselevel .dtsi file that describes the complete chip. But only the essential devices for a minimal system are enabled, and all other device are defined as nodes but disabled. This DT file for the SoC is meant to be the first included .dtsi file in the board's .dts file. Do not edit this SoC .dtsi file! Instead you customize a DT for a board by adding lines after that include statement  to redefine nodes & properties.

Even better is a new .dtsi of just your customizations included at the end of the board's .dts file.

where should I add this new .dtsi file? in my custom layer? and should I add something in my local conf to tell bitbake to use that .dtsi file? that's the part I'm confused
